# How come I can only visit the subdomain if I include the index.php in the address?

Tags: url

How come I can only visit the subdomain, e.g. subdomain.domain.com, if I include `index.php`?

`subdomain.domain.com`, doesn't work.

`subdomain.domain.com/index.php` works.

do I have to change something in the `httpd.conf` file?

I'm sorry if that's a stupid question, I just couldn't figure it out myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `index.php` in the `DirectoryIndex` of your `httpd.conf`. It is not included by default.